# Plots, by Label, frequency of words

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to create separates plot based on a label. My dataset is

```
    Label   Word    Frequency
439 10.0    glass   600
471 10.0    tv      34
463 10.0    screen  31
437 10.0    laptop  15
454 10.0    info    15
65  -1.0    dog 1
68  -1.0    cat 1
69  -1.0    win 1
70  -2.0    man 1
71  -2.0    woman   1
```

In this case I would expect three plots, one for 10, one for -1 and one for -2, with on the x axis Word column and on the y-axis the Frequency (it is already sorted in descending order by Label).

I have tried as follows:

```
df['Word'].hist(by=df['Label'])
```

But it seems to be wrong as the output is far away from the expected one.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be using a histogram here: a histogram plot is where the columns of your dataframe contain raw data, and the `hist` function buckets the raw values and finds the frequencies of each bucket, and then plots.

Your dataframe is already bucketed, with a column in which the frequencies have already been calculated; what you need is the `df.plot.bar()` method. Unfortunately, this is quite new, and does not yet allow a `by` parameter, so you have to deal with the subplots manually.

Full walkthrough code for the cut-down example you have provided follows. Obviously you can make it more generic by not hardcoding the number of subplots required in the line marked `[1]`.

```
# Set up:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import io
txt = """Label,Word,Frequency
10.0,glass,600
10.0,tv,34
10.0,screen,31
10.0,laptop,15
10.0,info,15
-1.0,dog,1
-1.0,cat,1
-1.0,win,1
-2.0,man,1
-2.0,woman,1"""
dfA = pd.read_csv((io.StringIO(txt)))

labels = dfA["Label"].unique()

# Set up subplots on which to plot.
# Make more generic by not hardcoding nrows and ncols in [1],
# but calculating them depending on how many labels you have.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2) # [1]
ax_list = axes.flatten() # axes is a list of lists;
                         # ax_list is a simple list which is easier to index.

# Loop through labels and plot the bar chart to the corresponding axis object.
for i in range(len(labels)):
  dfA[dfA["Label"]==labels[i]].plot.bar(x="Word", y="Frequency", ax=ax_list[i])
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help butterflyknife